# Calculating an integral with standard normal distribution.

Tags: integration, normal-distribution

Consider $$\lim_{n\to{\infty}}{\Phi_{0,1}^n{(x\ln{n}})}$$where x>0.

i.e.
$$\lim_{n\to{\infty}}[\int_{-\infty}^{x\ln{n}}\frac{1}{\displaystyle\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}}dy]^n$$
I think the answer would be 1, but I don’t know how to get it. Help me please.

Comment: Follows from the [asymptotics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Asymptotic_expansion) $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}xe^{x^2/2}\big(1-\Phi(x)\big)=1/\sqrt{2\pi}$ (an overkill, clearly).

Comment: Thank you...but I’m still puzzled. How can I get this limitation...?

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with this function...I tried use $\Phi(x)=\frac{1}{2}erfc(-\frac{x}{\sqrt2})$ but there has a summary...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll call $\Phi(x)=\Phi_{0,1}(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x(2\pi)^{-1/2}e^{-s^2/2}\,ds$. You can take the logarithm of that quantity of yours and consider $$\lim_{y\to\infty}y\ln\Phi(x\ln y)=\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\ln\Phi(-x\ln t)}{t}$$

Notice that for $x>0$ the limit on the RHS is an indeterminate form $\left[\frac 00\right]$ and since \begin{align}\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac d{dt}\ln\Phi(-x\ln t)&=\lim_{t\to 0^+}-\frac1{\Phi(-x\ln t)}\frac xt\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac12x^2\ln^2t}\\&=\lim_{t\to0^+}-\frac x{\sqrt{2\pi}\Phi(-x\ln t)}e^{-\ln t-\frac12 x^2\ln^2t}\\&=\left[-\frac x{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\infty}\right]=0^-\end{align} you can use l'Hopital, which yields $$\lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{\ln\Phi(-x\ln t)}{t}=0$$

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually this question is excerpted from another, and in order to continue, the value of the integration, I think, should be 1...so I’m puzzled why $\frac{x}{0^+}\times{e^\infty}=∞$.

Comment: @Maau Nice catch, I had a mistake in my derivative (I was doing $e^{x^2/2}$ instead of $e^{-x^2/2}$)

Comment: Thanks so much! Now it’s clear.